# Space-time and entropic gravity

Tags: gravity, spacetime, entropy

Gravity warps space-time, and gravity can be thought of as entropy (*[Entropic gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity)*). So, as spacetime expands, how is space-time entropy (or the inverse of gravity) affected?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, there is a problematic lack of verbs after "mean". As such, it's impossible to tell what the question is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Verlinde's idea of entropic gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity#Erik_Verlinde.27s_theory) is that the equations of general relativity can be produced by statistical arguments, much as used in thermodynamics. It's important to be clear that it is not an alternative theory of gravity. It is a way of explaining why the equations of general relativity have the form they do.

So the entropic gravity ideas would not change the way we describe the expanding universe. We would still explain it using Einstein's equations just as we always have done. What the entropic gravity does is to justify the use of Einstein's equations.

Verlinde suggested no concrete ideas for what might be physically happening. It's one of the strengths, or possibly weaknesses, of thermodynamics that the fine detail does not matter. Anyhow it would be premature to attach any physical interpretation to his ideas. In any case you should note that his ideas are hotly contested and far from being accepted as mainstream physics.

Comment: Yet, [amateurs claim it removes](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.twit.tv/audio/sn/sn0586/sn0586.mp3) [the need for dark matter](https://twit.tv/shows/security-now/episodes/586)  (based on a paper published early November 2016, "Emergent Gravity and the Dark Universe") - 1 h 44 min 26 secs - 1 h 51 min 28 secs. Would that change anything?

Comment: I would hardly call Eric Verlinde an amateur. Here's the quote from his paper: "The real reason why most physicists believe in the existence of particle dark matter is not the observations, but because there was no theoretical evidence nor a conceptual argument for the breakdown of these laws at the scales where the new phenomena are being observed. [...] The observed phenomena that are currently attributed to dark matter are the consquence of the emergent nature of gravity and are caused by an elastic response due to the volume law contribution to the entanglement entropy in our universe."